# SPARQL query timing out for WIkidata

Tags: sparql, mediawiki, mediawiki-api, wikidata-api

I am trying to run a SPARQL query. As soon as I try to query schema:about for a query , the query starts timing out. I am trying to write a query to get all cities with population greater than X.  Am I doing something wrong or is there a way to optimise it?
Original query which is working

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?cityLabel ?population ?country ?countryLabel ?loc WHERE {
  ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515 .
  ?city wdt:P1082 ?population .
  ?city wdt:P17 ?country .
  ?city wdt:P625 ?loc .
  FILTER (?population >= 1000000) .
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
  }
}
ORDER BY DESC(?population)
```

Query to get about article:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?cityLabel ?population ?country ?countryLabel ?loc ?article  WHERE {
  ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515 .
  ?city wdt:P1082 ?population .
  ?city wdt:P17 ?country .
  ?city wdt:P625 ?loc .
  FILTER (?population >= 1000000) .
  ?article schema:about ?city .
  ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>.
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
  }
}
ORDER BY DESC(?population)
```

Here is the link where I am trying to run the query: https://query.wikidata.org/

Comment: given that people having the same Wikidata queries at the same time as topic here, it's student project, right?

Comment: anyways: `SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?cityLabel ?population ?country ?countryLabel ?loc WHERE {
  {SELECT DISTINCT ?city {?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515 . hint:SubQuery hint:runOnce true}} 
  hint:Prior hint:runFirst true .
  ?city wdt:P1082 ?population .
  ?city wdt:P17 ?country .
  ?city wdt:P625 ?loc .
  ?article schema:about ?city .
  ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>.
  FILTER (?population >= 1000000) .
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
  }
}
ORDER BY DESC(?population)`

Comment: or even faster: `SELECT * {
{SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?cityLabel ?population ?country ?countryLabel ?loc {
  {SELECT DISTINCT ?city {?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515 . hint:SubQuery hint:runOnce true}} 
  hint:Prior hint:runFirst true .
  
  ?city wdt:P1082 ?population .
  ?city wdt:P17 ?country .
  ?city wdt:P625 ?loc .
  FILTER (?population >= 1000000) .
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
  }
}}
hint:Prior hint:runFirst true .
?city ^schema:about ?article .
?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>.
} 
ORDER BY DESC(?population)`